# Access Active window transation information from Quickbook application

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

is there any API Quickbook provide to grab information of the active window transaction ?

e.g if i have open a window of a Invoice in my Quickbook application then my application should be access that information from the Quickbook ?

if it is possible with QBXML ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: please see my answer for the same

Comment: If you accept an answer, this question will no longer appear in the `unanswered` questions list.

Comment: i found the solution with the menu subscription event

Comment: If you mark an answer as accepted, people looking for unanswered questions will see that this question has an accepted answer. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer by the event of the menu subscription with QBXML

when you click on the menu of the QB which you have subscribe and if any active window transaction is open then QB Menu click response is including `<currentwindow>` Tag with that.

Its include the Transaction ID and the Type of the transaction open.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in Quickbooks or QBXML.

Comment: i have one application which is doing this, but i don not know how it is performing it

Answer (score 0):

After researching all the things i found the solution from the menu subscription events.

When we subscribe any menu to quickbook , when we click on that menu from QB then if any Actvie window is open of any transaction for the QB it is retuning an XML with the CurrentWindow tag.

This will include the type of the QB Transation and the Transaction ID

Base on above info you can Query with QB and retrive the information for the same.

Thanks.